# How to pass remote parent span properly using NATS?

Tags: go, open-telemetry, opentracing, nats.io

I have a dummy example on [this repo](//github.com/kokizzu/jeager1)

I tried to pass current span context to a remote one so it would show the trace properly, what I've done:

```
go func() {
    _, span := otel.Tracer("natsC").Start(context.Background(), "publish")
    defer span.End()

    // send current span context as header
    spanCtx := span.SpanContext()
    spanJson, _ := spanCtx.MarshalJSON()
    log.Println(string(spanJson))
    msg, err := nc.RequestMsg(&nats.Msg{
        Subject: topic1, Data: []byte("whatever"), Header: nats.Header{
            "otelTrace": []string{string(spanJson)},
        },
    }, 2*time.Second)
    if L.IsError(err, `nc.Publish`) {
        return
    }
    log.Println(`reply:`, msg)
}()
```

On the receiver server:

```
_, err = nc.QueueSubscribe(topic1, "my-queue", func(msg *nats.Msg) {
    // take header and deserialize back to spanContext
    rsc := msg.Header.Get(`otelTrace`)
    parentSpanCtx := trace.SpanContext{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(rsc), &parentSpanCtx)
    L.IsError(err, `json.Unmarshal`)

    // use remote context as parent context
    _, span := otel.Tracer(`natsC`).Start(trace.ContextWithRemoteSpanContext(context.Background(), parentSpanCtx), topic1)
    defer span.End()

    data := string(msg.Data)
    fmt.Println(data)
    err = msg.Respond(msg.Data)
    L.IsError(err, `msg.Respond`) // ignore error
})
```

then I run it using this command `go run main.go natsC`.

both span shown on Jeager (localhost:16686) as separate spans, not correlated like in http/grpc example, what should I modify so it would considered as child span of the parent?

[image: uncorrelated1]
[image: uncorrelated2]

equivalent http/grpc example:

[image: correlated]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace@v1.11.1/trace.go` has the definitions for the context right, you can call MarshalJSON and have it spit something that *looks* useful but here's the thing. There is no equivalent unmarshalling function and the output is a string while the internal format is a fixed length byte array...

So to get it to work just dump the trace and span IDs into whatever format you like:

```
// Attach telemetry headers
headers := nats.Header{}
headers.Set(otelTraceID, span.SpanContext().TraceID().String())
headers.Set(otelSpanID, span.SpanContext().SpanID().String())
```

Then on the receive side you have to rebuild it manually into a SpanContext:

```
func getParentContext(msg *nats.Msg) (spanContext trace.SpanContext, err error) {
    var traceID trace.TraceID
    traceID, err = trace.TraceIDFromHex(msg.Header.Get(otelTraceID))
    if err != nil {
        return spanContext, err
    }
    var spanID trace.SpanID
    spanID, err = trace.SpanIDFromHex(msg.Header.Get(otelSpanID))
    if err != nil {
        return spanContext, err
    }
    var spanContextConfig trace.SpanContextConfig
    spanContextConfig.TraceID = traceID
    spanContextConfig.SpanID = spanID
    spanContextConfig.TraceFlags = 01
    spanContextConfig.Remote = true
    spanContext = trace.NewSpanContext(spanContextConfig)
    return spanContext, nil
}
```

Then actually use it:

```
remoteCtx, err := getParentContext(msg)
if err != nil {
    logrus.Fatal(err)
}

_, span := otel.Tracer(fqpn).Start(trace.ContextWithRemoteSpanContext(context.Background(), remoteCtx), msg.Subject)
defer span.End()
```

[image]